# A pipeline from the ocean to the desert causing a climate change for a drout in california a good idea?

Tags: water

[image] If I already had a crew that built a pipe line in california from the ocean to the sahara how long would it take to wet the dry lands with rain water and what kind of weather or cliamate change would accur would the changes be good for southern california. There is mass drout in california which spring and winter would last longer putting a change on climate?  This would be man made accept for the natural percipitation that would accur in the desert bringing maore rain and clouds and possible thunder and lighting storms could this as it is already patended a bigger and better climate change?

Comment: The salt in the sea water will poison the land.

Comment: This question has been dealt with in [What would be the effect of bringing seawater pipes to the Sahara desert?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/what-would-be-the-effect-of-bringing-seawater-pipes-to-the-sahara-desert/7560#7560)

Comment: As a matter of fact, California (or large parts of it - it's a diverse state) has been experiencing something of an excess of precipitation lately, with this year's Sierra snowpack being almost double the long-term average, and near-record rainfall in May: https://www.sacbee.com/news/weather-news/article230855969.html  California's water problems aren't due to a lack of water, but to an excess of population in certain areas.

Answer (score 2):

It's been proposed. Not for California, but for the Sahara, and the Empty Quarter in Arabia.

The notion is that you are creating an interior salt sea -- the equivalent of Great Salt lake.  Evaporation from that sea modifieds the local climate.

You have to move a LOT of water.

Done right,you can process the resulting salt for other products.  Bromine, Chlorine, etc.

A more interesting idea is to use this to MAKE power.

- Build a 10 km diameter greenhouse.
- Build a 2 or more kilometer high chimney.
- The outer part of the green house is floored with ponds of water with carbon suspended in the water.  Essentially dilute india ink.
- At the base of the chimney you have wind turbines.
- As air enters the green house it picks up heat and moisture.  The moist air in the chimney rises, drawing more air in.  As it rises it cools, water condenses, adding heat back into the system.  In effect you have a single updraft from a thunders storm.
- Done right, the water starts to rain out part way up.  You can collect the water as fresh water.